# getHighest function call in C++ producing 0 results in error

Tags: c++

Here is the code below. when I execute the code, the getLowest is working fine as it returns 13, which is correct. However, the getHighest is returning 0 when it should be 40. The return on screen is 0 when it should be 40. What is there I can change. I have already gave 4 int types and the calls are executing properly except the getHighest function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

//function prototype 
int getHighest(int numArray[], int numElements); 
int getLowest(int numArray[], int numElements);


int main()
{
    int numbers[4] = { 13, 2, 40, 25 };

    cout << "The highest number in the array is "
        << getHighest(numbers, 2) << "." << endl;
    cout << "The lowest number in the array is "
        << getLowest(numbers, 1) << "." << endl;


    system("Pause");
    return 0;



} // end of main function 

//******function definitions******
int getHighest(int numArray[], int numElements);
int getHighest(int numArray[], int numElements)
{
    return 0;
}
int getLowest(int numArray[], int numElements)
{
    //assign first elemet's value to the high variable
    int high = numArray[0];
    int low = numArray[0];

    //begin search with second element
    for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 3)
        if (numArray[sub] > high)
            high = numArray[sub];
    for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1)
    if (numArray[sub] > low)
        low = numArray[sub];

    //end if 
    //end for
    return low; 
    return high;


 //end of getHighest function

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why `return 0;` is returning 0, or what?

Comment: Or why when I take out 0 and replace with return high;

Comment: Here is what the code reads when executed. "The highest number in the array is 0. The lowest number in the array is 13. Press and key to continue....

Comment: `getHighest()` is not usefully implemented at all and always returns 0. Implement it, and everything is fine.

Comment: I thought it was implemented. What do I need to add to implement it ?

Comment: I thought it was implemented. What do I need to add to implement it ? is it somewhere in this part of the code that needs modified?  for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1)
  if (numArray[sub] > high)
   high = numArray[sub];
 for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1)
 if (numArray[sub] > low)
  low = numArray[sub];

Answer (score 0):

In the getLowest function you´re returning low, when you do a return instruction, it returns the value and exit whatever it was doing. In the getHighest you are returning directly a 0, you are not really doing anything there, I´ll propose a fix to your code:

```
     int getLowest(int numArray[])
        {
            //int high = numArray[0]; in this function let´s just search for the lowest
            int numElements = sizeof( numArray ) / sizeof( numArray[0] ); //This will count automatically the number of elements in your array
            int low = numArray[0];


            for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1)
            {
              if (numArray[sub] < low)
              low = numArray[sub];
            }
            return low; 

        }
```

.

```
  int getHighest(int numArray[])
        {
            int high = numArray[0]; 
            int numElements = sizeof( numArray ) / sizeof( numArray[0] );//This will count automatically the number of elements in your array
            for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1)
            {
                if (numArray[sub] > high)
                high= numArray[sub];
            }
            return high; 

        }
```

So for calling them you will just need to do this

```
cout << "The highest number in the array is "
        << getHighest(numbers) << "." << endl;
    cout << "The lowest number in the array is "
        << getLowest(numbers) << "." << endl;
```

Comment: Ok I am attempting to use. It says identifier "numarray" is undefined

Comment: Already edited, missed the capital letter of the numArray variable.